# How to change into a directory with a space in its name

Tags: bash, cd

I have this directory in CS50 IDE called "cs50 web" and want to `cd` into it. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how...

```
~/ $ cd cs50 web
bash: cd: too many arguments
~/ $ cd cs50-web
bash: cd: cs50-web: No such file or directory
~/ $ cd cs50_web
bash: cd: cs50_web: No such file or directory
~/ $ cd cs50web
bash: cd: cs50web: No such file or directory
~/ $ cd cs50 web
bash: cd: too many arguments
~/ $ cd cs50 web
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

Could somebody provide some advice for how I could `cd` into this folder?

Comment: You can escape the space: `cd cs50\ web`

Comment: @puffin Thanks! This worked for me.

Comment: *cd cs50\*web* or just *cd c\** works too

Answer (score 2):

1. Autocomplete: Type the first few characters and press tab to autocomplete (e.g., `cd cs5` then press `tab`).
2. Use quotes: `cd "cs50 web"`
3. Escape with backslash `cd cs50\ web`

I recommend practicing with the autocomplete as this can save you time and is pretty nice. Note that you can press tab multiple times to cycle through directories if multiple matches exist (or type a few more characters).